# Angular 9.0.4: using $localize: ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

if I execute "ng serve" I got this error message "ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of undefined".
It happends, because I'm using $localize at "partnerkunde-routing.module.ts"

```
children: [
      {
        path: 'post',
        component: PartnerPostComponent,
        data: { title: $localize`::Partner anlegen`, breadcrumb: 'anlegen' }
      },
...
```

In all other cases it works fine to do some localization. Any one an idea how I can solve it?
Thanks guys!

at "app-routing.module.ts"

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    // Routing für Lizenz Domäne
    path: 'partnerkunde',
    loadChildren: () => import('./domains/partnerkunde/partnerkunde.module').then(m => m.PartnerKundeModule)
  },
  {
    // Routing für Lizenz Domäne
    path: 'lizenz',
    loadChildren: () => import('./domains/lizenz/lizenz.module').then(m => m.LizenzModule)
  },
  {
    // Routing für den core einbinden
    path: 'core',
    loadChildren: () => import('./main/core/core.module').then(m => m.CoreModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'nachrichten',
    component: NachrichtenFormComponent,
    data: { title: $localize`:@@common_nachrichten_title:Liste empfangenen Nachrichten`}
  },
  {
    // Root-URL festlegen, bzw. Weiterleitung setzen
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/partnerkunde',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    // Seite wurde nicht gefunden
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  }
];
```

at "partnerkunde-routing.module.ts"

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    // Partner Liste
    path: 'partner',
    data: { title: $localize`:@@partnerkunde_parter-liste_title:Liste der Partner`, breadcrumb: 'Partner' },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'post',
        component: PartnerPostComponent,
        data: { title: $localize`::Partner anlegen`, breadcrumb: 'anlegen' }
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: PartnerListeComponent,
        data: {
           title: "Liste Partner", // $localize`:@@partnerkunde_partner-liste_title:Liste der Partner`,
           breadcrumb: "Liste", // $localize`:@@partnerkunde_partner-liste_breadcrumb:Liste`
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'put/:id',
        component: PartnerPutComponent,
        data: { title: 'Partner aktualisieren', breadcrumb: 'aktualisieren' }
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: If I use "ng serve --aot" it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue may be due to some pre-processing made by Angular build process.

You should consider moving your localize messages to separate file and then import them.

```
// localize.ts
export default pageTitle = $localize`:@@localize.key:`;

// routing.ts
import pageTitle from './localize';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    // Partner Liste
    path: 'partner',
    data: { title: pageTitle }
  }
];
```